# WPF creating resource dictionary that has many bindable parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have 5 WPF GeometryDrawing objects which are placed in a  resource dictionary, because theay can be used in different views. The Brush attribute of GeometryDrawing should be bound to Enum property in concrete viewmodel. Any of 5  GeometryDrawing objects can be place to WPF Image (see below), it depends on another Enum property. How it can be implemeneted? Please, let me know if any additional description is required. Thanks.

```
<Image Source="Should be any of [image1, image2, image3, image4, image4]"></Image>
```

Resource Dictionary:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <Geometry x:Key="geom1">#Some geometry</Geometry>
      <DrawingGroup x:Key="group1">
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=Background,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}" Geometry="{StaticResource geom1}" />
      </DrawingGroup>
      <DrawingImage x:Key="image1" Drawing="{StaticResource group1}" />

      <Geometry x:Key="geom2">#Some geometry</Geometry>
      <DrawingGroup x:Key="group2">
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=Background,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}" Geometry="{StaticResource geom2}" />
      </DrawingGroup>
      <DrawingImage x:Key="image2" Drawing="{StaticResource group2}" />

      <Geometry x:Key="geom3">#Some geometry</Geometry>
      <DrawingGroup x:Key="group3">
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=Background,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}" Geometry="{StaticResource geom3}" />
      </DrawingGroup>
      <DrawingImage x:Key="image3" Drawing="{StaticResource group3}" />

      <Geometry x:Key="geom4">#Some geometry</Geometry>
      <DrawingGroup x:Key="group4">
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=Background,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}" Geometry="{StaticResource geom4}" />
      </DrawingGroup>
      <DrawingImage x:Key="image4" Drawing="{StaticResource group4}" />

      <Geometry x:Key="geom5">#Some geometry</Geometry>
      <DrawingGroup x:Key="group5" >
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=Background,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}"{StaticResource geom5}" />
      </DrawingGroup>
      <DrawingImage x:Key="image5" Drawing="{StaticResource group5}" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Icon1">
            <Image  Source="{StaticResource image1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Icon2">
            <Image  Source="{StaticResource image2}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Icon3">
            <Image  Source="{StaticResource image3}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Icon4">
            <Image  Source="{StaticResource image4}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Icon5">
            <Image  Source="{StaticResource image5}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

And now in a View I use it like (for the sake of simplicity Background="Green" in ContentControl, it can be easily bound later.):

```
 <ContentControl Background="Green">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow1, Path=Id}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Icon2}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow1, Path=Id}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Icon3}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

In design time the image is shown perfectly but in **runtime the image is not rendered**.

Link to repo [Sample project](http://git%20clone%20https://vnozdrenkov@bitbucket.org/vnozdrenkov/wpf_stackoverflow.git)

Comment: I think you're going to need to use a datatemplate to do this. Drawinggroup is a freezable so if you put one in a resource dictionary it'll be frozen when you get it out. You would need to clone or unfreeze it to alter any property. You can prove that easy though. Give those a set brush. Merge your resource dictionary. Grab one of those groups out using application.current.resources["group5"] or whatever. Take a look at whether it's frozen or just try setting the brush and see what happens.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your reply. I have almost solved my problem, but now the image is not rendered in runtime, whereas in design time the preview is OK. Please, have a look at updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This post helped me with it [Bind to GeometryDrawing brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478380/wpf-creating-resource-dictionary-that-has-many-bindable-parameters/62490112#62490112). Thanks to Clemens. But for it I had to get rid of GeometryDrawing, because I didn't found the way of binding the Brush attribute.

Now my resource dictionary contains only Geometry objects:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="IconsResource" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6">

    <Geometry x:Key="ErrorOutline">F1 M24,24z M0,0z M11,15L13,15 13,17 11,17z M11,7L13,7 13,13 11,13z M11.99,2C6.47,2 2,6.48 2,12 2,17.52 6.47,22 11.99,22 17.52,22 22,17.52 22,12 22,6.48 17.52,2 11.99,2z M12,20C7.58,20 4,16.42 4,12 4,7.58 7.58,4 12,4 16.42,4 20,7.58 20,12 20,16.42 16.42,20 12,20z</Geometry>
    <Geometry x:Key="Check_circle">F1 M24,24z M0,0z M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12 2,17.52 6.48,22 12,22 17.52,22 22,17.52 22,12 22,6.48 17.52,2 12,2z M10,17L5,12 6.41,10.59 10,14.17 17.59,6.58 19,8 10,17z</Geometry>
    <Geometry x:Key="New_releases">F1 M24,24z M0,0z M23,12L20.56,9.22 20.9,5.54 17.29,4.72 15.4,1.54 12,3 8.6,1.54 6.71,4.72 3.1,5.53 3.44,9.21 1,12 3.44,14.78 3.1,18.47 6.71,19.29 8.6,22.47 12,21 15.4,22.46 17.29,19.28 20.9,18.46 20.56,14.78 23,12z M13,17L11,17 11,15 13,15 13,17z M13,13L11,13 11,7 13,7 13,13z</Geometry>
    <Geometry x:Key="Sync_problem">F1 M24,24z M0,0z M3,12C3,14.21,3.91,16.2,5.36,17.64L3,20 9,20 9,14 6.76,16.24C5.68,15.15 5,13.66 5,12 5,9.39 6.67,7.17 9,6.35L9,4.26C5.55,5.15,3,8.27,3,12z M11,17L13,17 13,15 11,15 11,17z M21,4L15,4 15,10 17.24,7.76C18.32,8.85 19,10.34 19,12 19,14.61 17.33,16.83 15,17.65L15,19.74C18.45,18.85 21,15.73 21,12 21,9.79 20.09,7.8 18.64,6.36L21,4z M11,13L13,13 13,7 11,7 11,13z</Geometry>
    <Geometry x:Key="Error">F1 M24,24z M0,0z M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12 2,17.52 6.48,22 12,22 17.52,22 22,17.52 22,12 22,6.48 17.52,2 12,2z M13,17L11,17 11,15 13,15 13,17z M13,13L11,13 11,7 13,7 13,13z</Geometry>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The main idea is to use **Path** element, so:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Path Stroke="{Binding ElementName=ColorBox, Path=Text}" Fill="{Binding ElementName=ColorBox, Path=Text}">
                    <Path.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource Check_circle}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" Value="2">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource Error}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" Value="3">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource ErrorOutline}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" Value="4">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource New_releases}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=Text}" Value="5">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{StaticResource Sync_problem}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Path.Style>
                </Path>
            <TextBox Name="TextBox"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="ColorBox">Green</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```